# hover over one element, transition another element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two divs A and B. div A is an image. Div B is a paragraph underneath div A.

I am trying to make it so that if I put the mouse over div A, the background and font colour of div B transition to different colours without affecting div A.
I currently have the :hover selector so div B changes if someone hovers over it. But I don't know how to affect div B while hovering over div A.

Any clues on how to achieve this?

EDIT:
Please see below for the structure of my code. I'm trying to make it so that if I hover over #image1, the background of #info1 and the font colour of its paragraph would change and so on so forth for the other two images.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <img id="image1" src="res/images/aimage1.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div id="info1" class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <p class="washed-out"> 1 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <img id="image2" src="res/images/aimage2.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div id="info2" class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <p class="washed-out"> 2 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <img id="image3" src="res/images/animage3.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </div>
        <div id="info3" class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
          <p class="washed-out"> 3 </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.washed-out{
  background: white;
  color: black;
  transition: background-color 300ms linear, color 1s linear;
}

.washed-out:hover{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: you should add some code

Comment: It is possible that you are looking for the [general sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors). Try providing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you trying to do this with css only or javascript? Show us some code about what you already tried.

Comment: I've added some code. I've tried doing it with both css and javascript, but can't manage to do it with either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the sibling selector `~` or the immediate sibling selector `+`

```css
img:hover + div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100">
<div>Hey there...I get red when you hover the image</div>
```

Update based on comment, possible CSS version

```css
.hoverme:hover + div .washed-out {
  color: red;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6 hoverme">
  <img id="image1" src="res/images/aimage1.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
</div>
<div id="info1" class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
  <p class="washed-out">1</p>
</div>
```

Update based on comment, possible JS version

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var imglist = document.querySelectorAll('img.img-responsive');
  for (var i = 0; i < imglist.length; i++) {
    imglist[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) { e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.add('infos');   
    })
    imglist[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function(e) { e.target.parentElement.nextElementSibling.classList.remove('infos');   
    })
  }
})
```

```css
div.infos .washed-out {
  color: red;
  background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
  <img id="image1" src="res/images/aimage1.png" class="img-responsive center-block">
</div>
<div id="info1" class="col-md-12 col-sm-6">
  <p class="washed-out">1</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The divs aren't direct siblings to each other though, I've add a code snippet if you could take a look

Comment: @LikeToLearnStuff Well, that changes everything ... as they are nested inside another element, this won't work. You either need a script or move the hover to the image's parent div.

Comment: Your updated version is working perfectly! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) - `element:hover + element`:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.container:first-child {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

/** if the 1st element is hovered, changed the 2nd **/
.container:hover + .container {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">Div 1</div>

<div class="container">Div 2</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use successor siblings `~` or immediate successor siblings `+` to make any change on `hover`

```css
img:hover ~ div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/100">
<div>Hey there...I get red when you hover the image</div>
<div>Hey there...I also get red when you hover the image</div>
```

Comment: What are the chances that you and I write the exact same words and sample layout?

Comment: I downvoted this since it looks like you copied [LGSon's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40982363/2518200) without adding anything useful.

Comment: no i just wanted to show you how the 2 div changind the colors because of `~` and for  got to add the 2nd div. And now updated it

Answer (score 0):

What you want can be done by javascript event handler.

Something like this:

```
var d1 = document.getElementById("div1");  // on hover on this div
var d2 = document.getElementById("div2");  // bring changes to this

d1.addEventListener("hover", callfun, false);

function callfun(){
    d2.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to register a hovering in and out handler as shown in the following answer:
[Event listener hover changing other element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39182186/event-listener-hover-changing-other-element)
Here is a slightly modified version of it to fit more closely to your need.

```
document.getElementById("Div-A").addEventListener("mouseenter",function (){
   document.getElementById("Div-B").style.backgroundColor = "red";
   document.getElementById("Div-B").style.backgroundColor = "Yellow"; 
});

document.getElementById("Div-A").addEventListener("mouseout",function (){
   document.getElementById("Div-B").style.backgroundColor = "";
   document.getElementById("Div-B").style.text = ""; 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
  function Myfunc1(){
     document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "green"
     document.getElementById("div2").style.backgroundColor = "white"}
  function Myfunc2(){
     document.getElementById("div2").style.backgroundColor = "red"
     document.getElementById("div1").style.backgroundColor = "white"}
</script>
     <pre><div id="div1" onmouseover="Myfunc1()"><img src=""><p> look</p></div>
     <div id="div2" onmouseover="Myfunc2()"><p>here</p></div></pre>
```